# Validate Json response in groovy + Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a question about a script that I would like to write.
I send request and the response is json.
to day I take the response to online tool like https://jsonlint.com/ that checks if it is a valid json.
Is there a way to get this in jmeter just boolean valid or Not valid.
regards

the code I wrote:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

the error I get

```
unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses after defining a new [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) instance

```
def json = null
try {
    json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
                                    //^^ here is your problem
    log.info("Valid JSON")
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info("Invalid JSON")        
}

boolean valid = json != null;
// do what you need with this "valid" boolean
```

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

try to parse json and if there is an error you will get parse exception.

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonText )
```

Comment: I tried to write the script       {def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());}  and I get error unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText

Comment: there was a mistake. just fixed. try again